# Android aplication compatibility with previous API

Tags: android, api, compatibility

I was given an application that has been running well in  API 16 and above. and I was assigned to make these applications can run well in the previous API. And my question is what should i considered to do this job? What can I do? and how to do it?

Thank you in advance, sorry for newbie question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Supporting Different Platform Versions**

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html

**For Supporting Multiple Screens**

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html